# Как предоставить пользователю право запускать/завершать демон с root привилегиями?

Tags: freebsd, linux

Здравствуйте.

Такая ситуация:

Есть машина, на которой необходимо запускать программу(если конкретно - snort но в принципе это не важно) как демон. Для корректной работы программе требуются root привилегии. Проблема в том что моя учётка не имеет прав суперпользователя.

Что уже пытался попробовать:

1. Пытался решить проблему с помощью присваивания бинарнику программы SUID бита, в этом случае всё хорошо, пока не требуется убить/перезапустить запущеный процесс(так как он запускается от имени root я конечно не могу его убить с помощью kill).
2. Думал на счёт перспективы написать враперы на СИ для убийства процесса, но пока оставил этот вариант на самый последний момент.

И, внимание, **вопрос**:

Можно ли (и если можно то как) предоставить обычному пользователю право запускать/завершать демон с root привилегиями.

Comment: Не прив**Е**легии, а прив**И**легии

Comment: спасибо, поправил, каюсь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Плюнул, написал на C врапер над скриптом с помощью system(3), присвоил suid bit. всё работает, всем спасибо.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    system("pidof=`ps ax |grep /usr/local/bin/snort |grep -v grep |awk '{print $1}'`\n"
        "if [ -z $pidof ] \n"
        "then\n"
        "echo \"cant find proc\"\n"
        "else\n"
        "echo \"pid is $pidof\"\n kill $pidof\n"
        "fi\n"
    );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @gg4me, писать свои программки это правильно. Обычно в подобных врапперах еще добавляют проверку (используя свой конф. файл) - может ли данный UID его запускать?

А вообще часто проблема решается скриптом из одной строки

    echo your-password | sudo -S your-command-as-root

Конечно, Вы должны иметь полномочия на запуск sudo и не бояться светить рутовый пароль. При желании пароль можно (в некоторой степени) скрыть. Поскольку вы любите писать - попрактикуйтесь сами.